# SendMessage in win32 project has different result

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sendmessage, win32gui

I have a win32 project that has 2 text windows(inputArea, outputArea) and 2 buttons(sendButton and ResetButton).

My problem is that when I press Reset I want to clear the text from both areas, and the inputArea gets cleared but the outputArea gets colored.

Here is the code I have tried:

```
case IDC_ResetButton:
{
   SendMessage(hwndInputArea, WM_SETTEXT, NULL, NULL);
   SendMessage(hwndOutputArea, WM_SETTEXT, NULL, NULL);
   break;
}
```

my intial inputArea:

[image]

my initial outputArea:

[image]

And here is what happens to outputArea when I press Reset:

[image]

Also, I tried each line of code separately and they work, but when I put both of them I get this result of the outputArea and I can't find out why.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try using [`SendMessageCallback`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644951(v=vs.85).aspx) instead.

Comment: Also, what `LRESULT` does `SendMessage` return in both cases, when it works and when it doesn't?

Comment: Genti Saliu, LRESULT is 1 in both cases, it works, it deletes the text from outputArea but I don't want the color to appear there.

Comment: Christopher Oicles, I tried it has the same result.

Comment: @Tom Sorry -- I deleted my suggestion after realizing it wouldn't help, but before I noticed your reply.  My next guess is that you might be setting the background color by handling one of the `WM_CTLCOLOR...` messages, detecting if hWnd is for your input control, and then changing the DC's background color (and brush) for that groovy background color.  But, if hWnd is for the other control, the handler just leaves the DC alone.  If this is the case, you might want to experiment with resetting the DC to the default background color when the handler is being called for the output hWnd.

Comment: Where does that [light salmon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salmon_(color)#Light_salmon) background come from? Please share the relevant code.

Comment: It comes from the WM_PAINT message                                  SetBkColor(hdc, RGB(255,228,196)); to color the background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that is editcontrol.
There are three options of color for that.

・text color
・background color
・drawing brush

```
HBRUSH CXxxDlg::OnCtlColor( CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor ) {

    HBRUSH hbr = CDialog::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);

    pDC->SetTextColor(RGB(0,0,0));  
    pDC->SetBkColor(RGB(192,192,192));　// …(1)
    HBRUSH hbrOrg = static_cast<HBRUSH>(GetStockObject(GRAY_BRUSH));　// …(2)

    return hbrOrg;
}
```

(1)(2)… make the same color

Answer (score -1):

try to get the handle of you edit control each time on your button case like this (Change IDC_EDIT1 and 2 to your edit control ID):

```
case IDC_ResetButton:
{
hwndInputArea = GetDlgItem(hwndDlg,IDC_EDIT1);
hwndOutputArea = GetDlgItem(hwndDlg,IDC_EDIT2);

SendMessage(hwndInputArea, WM_SETTEXT, 0, NULL);
SendMessage(hwndOutputArea, WM_SETTEXT, 0, NULL);
break;
}
```

Comment: As his existing code already alters both windows it is clear that he already has the correct window handles.

Comment: i just tested the same action and when i got the handle outside of the case it's not getting the same handle so it can be a handle problem, handle can be saved in WM_COMMAND case or in the button click event case.